# i want to play the songs

Tags: javascript, html

i am getting this error '**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains') at HTMLElement**'....i am stack on this...please help

i have been trying to code so that i could make the songs play but am stack, if any can help with the code i will be glad.

**My Html:**

```
<div class="player">
<div class="cover"></div>
<nav>
    <div class="left">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <i class="material-icons">queue_music</i>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="player-ui">
    <div class="title">
        <h3>Hello</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh repeat"></i>
        <p>Adele</p>
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up volume"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="played">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <i class="fa fa-backward prev"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-play play"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-forward next"></i>
    </div>
    <audio controls class="audio" >
        <source src="music/Ace of Base - All That She Wants.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

**Declaration:**

```
const pauseIconClassName = 'fa-pause'
const playIconClassName = 'fa-play'
const equalizerIconClassName = 'material-icons'

const musicPlayer = document.querySelectorAll('.player');
const playBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.play');

const audio = document.querySelectorAll('.audio');
```

**Function:**

```
playBtn.forEach((playBtn) => {

playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const isPlaying = musicPlayer.classList.contains('.play');

    if (isPlaying) {
        pauseSong();
    } else {
        playSong();
    }

});
});
```

Comment: do not post pictures of code, post the code - clearly, whatever `musicPlayer` is, it doesn't have a property called `classList`

Comment: please can i get more elaboration on that @JaromandaX

Comment: `musicPlayer` is NOT an element, therefore it does NOT have a classList (hint: check what `querySelectorAll` returns

Answer (score 1):

```js
let now_playing = document.querySelector(".now-playing");
let track_art = document.querySelector(".track-art");
let track_name = document.querySelector(".track-name");
let track_artist = document.querySelector(".track-artist");

let playpause_btn = document.querySelector(".playpause-track");
let next_btn = document.querySelector(".next-track");
let prev_btn = document.querySelector(".prev-track");

let seek_slider = document.querySelector(".seek_slider");
let volume_slider = document.querySelector(".volume_slider");
let curr_time = document.querySelector(".current-time");
let total_duration = document.querySelector(".total-duration");

let track_index = 0;
let isPlaying = false;
let updateTimer;

// Create new audio element
let curr_track = document.createElement('audio');

// Define the tracks that have to be played
let track_list = [
  {
    name: "Night Owl",
    artist: "Broke For Free",
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2264753/pexels-photo-2264753.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250",
    path: "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/WFMU/Broke_For_Free/Directionless_EP/Broke_For_Free_-_01_-_Night_Owl.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Enthusiast",
    artist: "Tours",
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3100835/pexels-photo-3100835.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250",
    path: "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/no_curator/Tours/Enthusiast/Tours_-_01_-_Enthusiast.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Shipping Lanes",
    artist: "Chad Crouch",
    image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1717969/pexels-photo-1717969.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250&w=250",
    path: "https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/ccCommunity/Chad_Crouch/Arps/Chad_Crouch_-_Shipping_Lanes.mp3",
  },
];

function random_bg_color() {

  // Get a number between 64 to 256 (for getting lighter colors)
  let red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 64;
  let green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 64;
  let blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + 64;

  // Construct a color withe the given values
  let bgColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";

  // Set the background to that color
  document.body.style.background = bgColor;
}

function loadTrack(track_index) {
  clearInterval(updateTimer);
  resetValues();
  curr_track.src = track_list[track_index].path;
  curr_track.load();

  track_art.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + track_list[track_index].image + ")";
  track_name.textContent = track_list[track_index].name;
  track_artist.textContent = track_list[track_index].artist;
  now_playing.textContent = "PLAYING " + (track_index + 1) + " OF " + track_list.length;

  updateTimer = setInterval(seekUpdate, 1000);
  curr_track.addEventListener("ended", nextTrack);
  random_bg_color();
}

function resetValues() {
  curr_time.textContent = "00:00";
  total_duration.textContent = "00:00";
  seek_slider.value = 0;
}

// Load the first track in the tracklist
loadTrack(track_index);

function playpauseTrack() {
  if (!isPlaying) playTrack();
  else pauseTrack();
}

function playTrack() {
  curr_track.play();
  isPlaying = true;
  playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
}

function pauseTrack() {
  curr_track.pause();
  isPlaying = false;
  playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';;
}

function nextTrack() {
  if (track_index < track_list.length - 1)
    track_index += 1;
  else track_index = 0;
  loadTrack(track_index);
  playTrack();
}

function prevTrack() {
  if (track_index > 0)
    track_index -= 1;
  else track_index = track_list.length;
  loadTrack(track_index);
  playTrack();
}

function seekTo() {
  let seekto = curr_track.duration * (seek_slider.value / 100);
  curr_track.currentTime = seekto;
}

function setVolume() {
  curr_track.volume = volume_slider.value / 100;
}

function seekUpdate() {
  let seekPosition = 0;

  if (!isNaN(curr_track.duration)) {
    seekPosition = curr_track.currentTime * (100 / curr_track.duration);

    seek_slider.value = seekPosition;

    let currentMinutes = Math.floor(curr_track.currentTime / 60);
    let currentSeconds = Math.floor(curr_track.currentTime - currentMinutes * 60);
    let durationMinutes = Math.floor(curr_track.duration / 60);
    let durationSeconds = Math.floor(curr_track.duration - durationMinutes * 60);

    if (currentSeconds < 10) { currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds; }
    if (durationSeconds < 10) { durationSeconds = "0" + durationSeconds; }
    if (currentMinutes < 10) { currentMinutes = "0" + currentMinutes; }
    if (durationMinutes < 10) { durationMinutes = "0" + durationMinutes; }

    curr_time.textContent = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;
    total_duration.textContent = durationMinutes + ":" + durationSeconds;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Simple Music Player</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="player">
<div class="details">
  <div class="now-playing">PLAYING x OF y</div>
  <div class="track-art"></div>
  <div class="track-name">Track Name</div>
  <div class="track-artist">Track Artist</div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="prev-track" onclick="prevTrack()"><i class="fa fa-step-backward fa-2x"></i></div>
  <div class="playpause-track" onclick="playpauseTrack()"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i></div>
  <div class="next-track" onclick="nextTrack()"><i class="fa fa-step-forward fa-2x"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="slider_container">
  <div class="current-time">00:00</div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="seek_slider" onchange="seekTo()">
  <div class="total-duration">00:00</div>
</div>
<div class="slider_container">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-down"></i>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="99" class="volume_slider" onchange="setVolume()">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
</div>
</div>
```